# How to prove $(F,+)$ and $(F\setminus \{0\},\cdot)$ aren't isomorphic, where $(F,+,\cdot)$ is an arbitrary field .

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, contest-math

> Assume $(F,+,\cdot)$ is an arbitrary field. How to prove $(F,+)$ and $(F\setminus \{0\},\cdot)$ aren't isomorphic?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: @rschwieb:yeah as a group isomorphism

Comment: And you want to prove this for *every* field or you just want a counterexample?

Comment: i want prove for all field (arbitrary fields  )

Comment: Consider elements of finite order.

Comment: I think you can say something like that. For every field $(k,+)$ is divisible so is injective. This means that it can be true only for algebraic closed fields. If field has characteristic $0$ then its not true because $(k,+)$ dont have elements of finite order. I dont know what to do with infinite algebraic closed fields of finite characteristic.

Comment: If $k$ is algebraic closed of characteristic $p$ then in $(k,+)$ there is no elements of order coprime to $p$.

Comment: What is the contest, and has it ended?

Comment: @ GEdgar :i think Iranian competition math

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If $\operatorname{char}(F) \neq 2$ then $(-1)$ has order $2$ in $(F^{\times},\cdot)$, but there is no element of order $2$ in $(F,+)$.

If $\operatorname{char}(F)=2$ then any element has order $2$ in $(F,+)$ but no element has order $2$ in $(F^{\times}, \cdot)$ as

$$x^2=1 \Rightarrow (x-1)^2=0 \Rightarrow x-1=0$$

Answer (score 3):

$\bullet$ if $k$ has not characteristic $2$, then if $f$ is an isomorphism from $(k^*,.)$ to $(k,+)$ we have: $0=f(1)=f((-1)^2)=2 f(-1)$ , then $f(-1)=0$ and $f(1)=f(-1)$, that is not possible since $f$ is injective.

$\bullet$ if $k$ has characteristic $2$, let  $x \in k^*$; then $f(x^2)=2f(x)=0=f(1)$ that gives $x^2=1$ and then $x=1$. But $f$  is an isomorphism from $k \backslash\{0\}$ to $k$ gives $k$ is an infinite set.